# How to use Flink SQL to create a table with the avro schema which has a complicated array type

Tags: apache-flink, avro, flink-sql

I try to use FlinkSQL to create a table with Avro format, but the avro schema is a little bit complicated which is like this:

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "name":"Record",
    "namespace":"example.avro",
    "fields":[
        {
            "name":"market",
            "type":"string"
        },
        {
            "name":"fruits",
            "type":[
                "null",
                {
                    "type":"array",
                    "items":[
                        "null",
                        {
                            "type":"record",
                            "name":"apple",
                            "fields":[
                                {
                                    "name":"price",
                                    "type":"int"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"counts",
                                    "type":"long"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"record",
                            "name":"banana",
                            "fields":[
                                {
                                    "name":"location",
                                    "type":"string"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name":"date",
                                    "type":"string"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default":null
        },
        {
            "name":"new_fruits",
            "type":[
                "null",
                {
                    "type":"array",
                    "items":[
                        "null",
                        "apple",
                        "banana"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "default":null
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that the array type from avro schema contains two different types but the array type of flink can only contain one type, I tried to define the type: ARRAY<ROW,ROW> in FlinkSQL DDL, but got syntax error. The whole DDL is shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE kafka_avro_source(
  `market`                STRING NOT NULL,
  `fruits`                 ARRAY<ROW<`price` INT NOT NULL, `counts` BIGINT NOT NULL>, ROW<`location` STRING NOT NULL, `date` STRING NOT NULL>>,
  `new_fruits`             ARRAY<ROW<`price` INT NOT NULL, `counts` BIGINT NOT NULL>, ROW<`location` STRING NOT NULL, `date` STRING NOT NULL>>
) WITH(
  'connector' = 'kafka',
  'topic' = 'avro_topic',
  'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '192.168.1.1:9092',
  'properties.group.id' = 'testGroup',
  'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format' = 'avro',
  'properties.sasl.kerberos.service.name' = 'kafka',
  'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
  'properties.kerberos.domain.name' = 'hadoop.com'
);
```

How could I use SQL to create a table with this avro schema, assume can not change the avro schema?

Comment: Can you please post the full exception? The DDL you showed looks fine from a first look and it should work.

Comment: Are you found the solution ?